# Tensorflow Can not train Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have followed this Tutorial to train my Custom Object but at the Training the Model step by executing this command :

python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config

I get this result:

```
(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\sid\Documents\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\legacy>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\sid\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "C:\Users\sid\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Stack Overflow is not a "please explain what is wrong with this" website. We can't help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: I think, I have provided information

Comment: I mean "more" information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the package **“nets”**.

In Linux this means typing this into the terminal:

```
pip install nets
```

Of course, then you need to add an import line into the python script:

```
import nets
```